# Can I run direct burial line in a conduit from the ground to the electrical box?

Tags: conduit

Can I run direct burial line in a conduit from the ground to the electrical box? Just the 4 or 5 feet from ground to box? Can I run it in conduit above ground along the building for 20 feet? The is the wire:

https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/2-2-2-4-dyke-underground-secondary-distribution-cable.html

Comment: Is the electrical box you're terminating it in inside or outside? Also, how far off the ground is the run along the building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Direct burial" means that the cable is rated to be in direct contact with the ground and keep the ground water away from the wires inside. It does not mean that it is *only* to be used in direct contact with dirt.

Feel free to wire your whole house with direct burial cable if you'd like, just be prepared to pay through the nose for it. (Just be sure to use wire *also* designated RHH/RHW-2 to do this - it's flame retardant and approved for indoor use. It must be used even if running in conduit.)

Long way of saying "yes", feel free to put it in a conduit as it comes out of the ground and makes its run to wherever you're terminating it. Actually, unless it's coming directly into a building, you'll be required by code to run it in conduit to protect it. Just make sure that your outdoor junction box is properly watertight.

Comment: URD/USE that isn't also designated RHH/RHW-2 can't be used indoors, *even in conduit*, as the insulation on it isn't flame-retardant

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - thanks for that. I was being a bit sarcastic, but I'll pull that statement out - I don't want somebody being mislead.